# i need change lenguage of microsoft edge for selenium automation --lang=es

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, microsoft-edge

i need change the language to --lang=es in microsoft-edge selenium java.
Because can't the page see in english and need in spanish

Comment: May I know whether your issue has been solved or not? If not, please share it in here. We can work together to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, its working:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options
            
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--lang=es")
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
prefs = {"translate_whitelists": {'en':'es'},
               "translate":{"enabled":"true"}}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)
            
driver = webdriver.Edge(service=Service(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.microsoft.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on **AbiSaran's** answer (which is in Python), I modified it into a Java one.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeOptions;


public class EdgeTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "C:\\path\\to\\msedgedriver.exe");
        EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--lang=es");
        EdgeDriver driver = new EdgeDriver(options);
        try {
            driver.get("https://bing.com");
            WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("sb_form_q"));
            element.sendKeys("WebDriver");
            element.submit();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } finally {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}
```